# Response for preflight has invalid http status code 405 angular 5 in chrome

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular5

[image]I am getting 405 error
i have attached the screenshot and code for review.

```
getDetails(rolename: Role): Observable<Role> {
        let value = Array();
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');        
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        var passData = {
            "Abc": "khkh",
            "cde": "hkhk",
            "fgh": "hkhk",
            "ijk": "acc"
        };
        let body = this.serializeObj(passData);

        return  this.http.post("http://localhost/service.svc/GetResults",           
           body,            
           options).pipe(
              map((response:  Response)  =>  {
                  debugger;
                 return  <Response>response;
              })).catch(this.handleErrorObservable);

    }
```

i have added cors in webconfig

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />        
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

my Post method is pointing to WCF Rest

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                                   RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,
                                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                                   UriTemplate = "GetResults")]
        List<ResponceModel> GetResults(Model request);
```

I cant able to post . please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer

I hosted the application in same server and tried to run in the same appdomain . so there was no cross domain issue occured. thus my issue solved.
Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

URL must contain port number which is missing in your request. Please add and check.

Comment: i used POSTMan in that case it is working without port number